# bootstrap3 grid with php

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid

I want to make something like this : http://s12.postimg.org/u07k9qkt9/image.png

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>

 <div class="row">

 <div class='col-lg-6'><h3>As melhores músicas para treinar no mês de todas as tentações</h1><h4>Desporto</h5> 
  <div class='row'>
  <div class='col-lg-3'><img src='img/ex1.JPG' class='img-thumbnail' width='200px' height='115px' /></div>
  <div class='col-lg-9'>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sed solum apeirian expetendis ad, nam assum latine apeirian ne, mea no omnis integre sententiae. Ea sea saperet qualisque repudiare, eam suas dolore gloriatur at, essent malorum tractatos eu quo. An per eruditi phaedrum. Voluptua prodesset voluptatum ut vel. Causae impedit et vis.
VER MAIS
2015-12-10 04:27:20</div>
  </div></div>

   <div class='col-lg-6'><h3>As melhores músicas para treinar no mês de todas as tentações</h1><h4>Desporto</h5> 
  <div class='row'>
  <div class='col-lg-3'><img src='img/ex1.JPG' class='img-thumbnail' width='200px' height='115px' /></div>
  <div class='col-lg-9'>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sed solum apeirian expetendis ad, nam assum latine apeirian ne, mea no omnis integre sententiae. Ea sea saperet qualisque repudiare, eam suas dolore gloriatur at, essent malorum tractatos eu quo. An per eruditi phaedrum. Voluptua prodesset voluptatum ut vel. Causae impedit et vis.
VER MAIS
2015-12-10 04:27:20</div>
  </div></div>


 </div>


  <div class="row">

 <div class='col-lg-6'><h3>As melhores músicas para treinar no mês de todas as tentações</h1><h4>Desporto</h5> 
  <div class='row'>
  <div class='col-lg-3'><img src='img/ex1.JPG' class='img-thumbnail' width='200px' height='115px' /></div>
  <div class='col-lg-9'>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sed solum apeirian expetendis ad, nam assum latine apeirian ne, mea no omnis integre sententiae. Ea sea saperet qualisque repudiare, eam suas dolore gloriatur at, essent malorum tractatos eu quo. An per eruditi phaedrum. Voluptua prodesset voluptatum ut vel. Causae impedit et vis.
VER MAIS
2015-12-10 04:27:20</div>
  </div></div>

   <div class='col-lg-6'><h3>As melhores músicas para treinar no mês de todas as tentações</h1><h4>Desporto</h5> 
  <div class='row'>
  <div class='col-lg-3'><img src='img/ex1.JPG' class='img-thumbnail' width='200px' height='115px' /></div>
  <div class='col-lg-9'>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sed solum apeirian expetendis ad, nam assum latine apeirian ne, mea no omnis integre sententiae. Ea sea saperet qualisque repudiare, eam suas dolore gloriatur at, essent malorum tractatos eu quo. An per eruditi phaedrum. Voluptua prodesset voluptatum ut vel. Causae impedit et vis.
VER MAIS
2015-12-10 04:27:20</div>
  </div></div>


 </div>



  <div class="row">

 <div class='col-lg-6'><h3>As melhores músicas para treinar no mês de todas as tentações</h1><h4>Desporto</h5> 
  <div class='row'>
  <div class='col-lg-3'><img src='img/ex1.JPG' class='img-thumbnail' width='200px' height='115px' /></div>
  <div class='col-lg-9'>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sed solum apeirian expetendis ad, nam assum latine apeirian ne, mea no omnis integre sententiae. Ea sea saperet qualisque repudiare, eam suas dolore gloriatur at, essent malorum tractatos eu quo. An per eruditi phaedrum. Voluptua prodesset voluptatum ut vel. Causae impedit et vis.
VER MAIS
2015-12-10 04:27:20</div>
  </div></div>

   <div class='col-lg-6'><h3>As melhores músicas para treinar no mês de todas as tentações</h1><h4>Desporto</h5> 
  <div class='row'>
  <div class='col-lg-3'><img src='img/ex1.JPG' class='img-thumbnail' width='200px' height='115px' /></div>
  <div class='col-lg-9'>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sed solum apeirian expetendis ad, nam assum latine apeirian ne, mea no omnis integre sententiae. Ea sea saperet qualisque repudiare, eam suas dolore gloriatur at, essent malorum tractatos eu quo. An per eruditi phaedrum. Voluptua prodesset voluptatum ut vel. Causae impedit et vis.
VER MAIS
2015-12-10 04:27:20</div>
  </div></div>


 </div>


</div>
```

but i wanted by printing data with php. I know this isn't the correct way of doing so i tried something like this, but it didn't worked:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<h2> Últimos Artigos  </h2>

<?php

$query = "Select * from `artigos` INNER JOIN `categorias` ON artigos.id_categoria=categorias.id_categoria order by `data` desc";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
  $titulo = $row['titulo'];
  $corpo = $row['corpo'];
  $img = $row['img'];
  $data = $row['data'];
  $idart = $row['id_artigo'];
  $nomecat = $row['name_categoria'];

?>


<?php 
    echo " 
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-lg-6'><h3>As melhores músicas para treinar no mês de todas as tentações</h1><h4>Desporto</h5> 
  <div class='row'>
  <div class='col-lg-3'><img src='img/ex1.JPG' class='img-thumbnail' width='200px' height='115px' /></div>
  <div class='col-lg-9'>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sed solum apeirian expetendis ad, nam assum latine apeirian ne, mea no omnis integre sententiae. Ea sea saperet qualisque repudiare, eam suas dolore gloriatur at, essent malorum tractatos eu quo. An per eruditi phaedrum. Voluptua prodesset voluptatum ut vel. Causae impedit et vis.
VER MAIS
2015-12-10 04:27:20</div>
  </div></div></div>";

}  
?>



</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to do this way

```html
echo  <<< _END

   <div class='row'>
  <div class='col-lg-6'><h3>As melhores músicas para treinar no mês de todas as tentações</h1><h4>Desporto</h5> 
  <div class='row'>
  <div class='col-lg-3'><img src='img/ex1.JPG' class='img-thumbnail' width='200px' height='115px' /></div>
  <div class='col-lg-9'>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sed solum apeirian expetendis ad, nam assum latine apeirian ne, mea no omnis integre sententiae. Ea sea saperet qualisque repudiare, eam suas dolore gloriatur at, essent malorum tractatos eu quo. An per eruditi phaedrum. Voluptua prodesset voluptatum ut vel. Causae impedit et vis.
VER MAIS
2015-12-10 04:27:20</div>
  </div></div></div>

_END;
```

Comment: It still doesn't change anything :/